# Sessão php é quebrada quando logo em dois sites no mesmo apache server

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache, session

Tenho dois sites que realizam a autenticação do usuário e logo após criam uma sessão para o mesmo, os dois sites acessam o mesmo banco de dados e portanto a estrutura usuário retornada pela instrução:

```
$usuario = $this->db->get('usuarios').result();
```

possui os mesmos campos, a sessão é criado assim:

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('logged' => true, 'usuario' => $usuario[0]));
```

todas as páginas dos dois sites redirecionam o usuário para a tela de login caso o campo `logged` não esteja setado como `true` na sessão, os sites funcionam normalmente(posso até abrir várias abas para um mesmo site), porém, se eu autenticar em um deles e tentar acessar qualquer página do outro, as sessões criadas são destruídas(em ambos os sites se existirem). Estou usando:

> codeigniter 2.2.1, PHP/5.4.19, Apache/2.4.4

.

Eu realmente não faço ideia do porque disso.

Comment: Provavelmente esse é um padrão do CodeIgniter, quando ele detecta duas sessões iguais no mesmo cliente e domínio ele encerra a sessão. Você poderia apenas mudar o nome dessas variáveis que acho que daria certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca o path de sessao pra cada site(Considerando que há duas instalacoes do Codeigniter).

Dentro do arquivo config.php em application/config procure pela linha:

```
$config['cookie_path'] = '/';
```

E coloque o path de cada site em cada config:

```
$config1.php
$config['cookie_path'] = '/site1';

$config2.php
$config['cookie_path'] = '/site2';
```

Comment: funcionou, da pra ter uma ideia do porque mas será que da pra explicar o porque disso? obrigado!

Comment: A sessão trabalha no servidor e o cookie no lado cliente, mas pra identificar de qual site aquela sessao pertence o servidor verifica as informacoes que estao contidas no cookie, e é ae que entra a ideia de colocar o path, que seria basicamente uma pasta com o nome de cada site seu e nele as informacoes relevantes pro seu servidor identificar onde esta os dados que ele precisa.

Comment: Se deu certo marque a resposta como correta para assim ajudar os demais usuarios.